# Adapting readmacros UCI Lisp code to common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to make the common lisp equivalent of this UCI Lisp/Interlisp helper function for a pattern mather.

```
(DRM /? (LAMBDA () (LIST '*VAR* (READ]
```

The documentation is a follows:

```
-Variables, which are used by the pattern matcher, start with a question mark ("?"), as in ?FOO.
-This is converted internally to (*VAR* role-name), so ?FOO becomes (*VAR* FOO).
-The DRM defines ? to convert itself to *VAR* when it is read
```

This is my current implementation of it:

```
(set-macro-character #\? (lambda () (list '*var* (read))))
```

But when I ran the match function below:

```
(match (ptrans (actor ?x) (object ?x) (to (store)))
   (ptrans (actor (person)) (object (person)) (to (store))) nil)
```

I get the following error that's coming from DRM function:

```
*** - EVAL/APPLY: too many arguments given to :LAMBDA
```

Is my implementation correct?

Comment: The function should accept two arguments, but the lambda you associate with the macro character takes none: see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm for details and examples

Answer (score 0):

Reader macro functions need to take two arguments: one for the stream from which they can read the source code, and one for the character that triggered them to be called. If you change your implementation to

```
(set-macro-character #\? (lambda (stream char)
                           (declare (ignore char))
                           (list '*var* (read stream))))
```

then any occurrence of `?x` will be read as `(*VAR* X)`.
Note that this will be evaluated if used as a function argument, which will cause an error if *VAR* is not a bound function / macro.

You probably want `?x` to be read in as `'(*VAR* X)` (note the quote) to get the list as data.
In that case you should do this:

```
(set-macro-character #\? (lambda (stream char)
                           (declare (ignore char))
                           (list 'quote
                                 (list '*var* (read stream)))))
```

to prevent evaluation of the form the reader macro function returns.